# Как поменять стиль widget'a B который находится на witget'e A при изменение property widget'a A

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, qwidget, qss

У меня есть Widget в на котором находится, например QLabe цвет которого я хочу менять в зависимости от property моего Widget'a, но я не понимаю как в таком случае должна выглядеть таблица стилей, пытался сделать что то вроде

```
QLabel[foo=true] { color : red;}
```

Пробовал другие selected'ы типа *, QWidget или по имени.
Однако, проблема тут в том что такое динамическое свойство есть только у Родителя, а не у QLabel. Пробовал создать такое же свойство у QLabel, но мне надо менять отрисов QLabel задаваю property у всего Widget'a.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте селектор на основе property у родительского виджета.
Что то типа:

```
QWidget[foo=true] QLabel { color : red;}
```

Потом не забудьте сделать unpolish() и polish() у  всего окна, после изменения данного property.